# Disable the same buttons on the basis of id in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Actually I am new to react . What I am doing here is,

I have few buttons like,

```
<div className="rowContent">
            {(props.data.id === 0) ? null :
                <span className="">
                    <button type="button" id={props.type + props.index} className="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm standard-btn-50" onClick={(e) => { props.onRemoveRow(e, props.data.id, props.type, props.noc) }}
                    >-</button>
                </span>}
            {(props.data.id === 0) ?
                <span>
                    <button type="button" id={props.type + props.index} className="btn btn-primary btn-sm standard-btn-50 margin-left-0" onClick={(e) => { props.onAddRow(e, props.data.id, props.type, props.data.level) }}
                        disabled={(props.limitExcedded) || (!props.data.technology) || (!props.data.type) || (!props.data.count)}
                    >+</button>
                </span> : null}
        </div>
```

so here, the buttons are same for the three divs. I mean its rendering in a loop depends upon the type.

SO, what I am doing, I want to disable this buttons on some conditions. SO, here I am passing one prop. Now, What happens is if that props becomes true then that particular divs button gets disabled ,

but If the props becomes false for the another div that time the previous button which was for the first div also gets enabled.

```
this.state = {
      technologies: [],
      showLowError: false,
      showHighError: false,
      showMediumError: false
    }
```

Now, these three are the variables for different rows. Now,  Here

```
{(props.data.id === 0) ? <button type="button" disabled={(props.limitExceddedLow) || (props.limitExceddedHigh) || (props.limitExceddedMedium) || (!props.data.technology) || (!props.data.type) || (!props.data.count)} className="btn btn-primary btn-block h-20" onClick={(e) => { props.onAddRow(e, props.data.id, props.type, props.data.level) }}>+</button> : null}
```

Now, still what happens is if any one of them is true then it will disable others as well.

So, I don't understand why this is happening? can any one help me with this ?

Comment: This is because `props.data.id`  is same for all rows, You need to have flags for each row.

Comment: Can you post your full `render()` code.

Comment: Actually it's a big lines of code in render. But I think you are right it might be because of that id

Comment: I have added the flags for the each row as a state variable but after that for the disable button. I have added an || condition there so because of that if any one of them is true then it becomes true

Comment: Can post the update code plz...

Comment: @kiranvj Updated my code please check. Because there I am using a || condition

Comment: What are the new flags and how are that flags are related to the row? How many rows are there?

Comment: Actually here, there are three main row, on click of button respective to that row, that type row gets added . and if you delete then that row gets removed. So, I am using map to render the same element thrice

Comment: @kiranvj I have updated then code

Answer (score 0):

take a variable ( var current_disable )for storing the Id of disable button 
when prob become true for another button , ebable privious butoon by using curent_disable variable and store the new ID of this button